# C# convert viewstate to bool array

Tags: c#, arrays

How I can convet viewstate to bool array

```
private bool[] clientCollapse
{
    get { return Convert.ToBoolean(ViewState["Collapse"]); }
    set { ViewState["Collapse"] = value; }
}
```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private bool[] clientCollapse
{
    get { return (bool[])ViewState["Collapse"]; }
    set { ViewState["Collapse"] = value; }
}
```

if will work if you set those values only using this propery, otherwise you can but there other type and cast will not work

BTW common naming convention for C# requires property names to start with capital: `ClientCollapse`

Answer (score 1):

try changing your getter to:

```
get { return ViewState["Collapse"] as bool[]; }
```

this will return null if it's not set.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using casts to do this:

```
private bool [] clientCollapse
{
    get { return (bool[]) ViewState["Collapse"]); }
    set { ViewState["Collapse"] = value; }
}
```

ASP.NET's serialization of view state will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
private bool[] clientCollapse
{
    get { return (bool[])ViewState["Collapse"] ?? new bool[0]; }
    set { ViewState["Collapse"] = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool [] clientCollapse
{
    get { return (ViewState["Collapse"] as bool[]); }
    set { ViewState["Collapse"]; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use extension methods so that you use it `ViewState<byte[]>.GetTypedData(key)`:

```
public static class ViewStateExtensions
    {

         public static T GetTypedData<T>(this StateBag bag, string key)
         {
             return (T) bag[key];
         }

         public static void SetTypedData<T>(this StateBag bag, string key, T value)
         {
             bag[key] = value;
         }

    }
```